# Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in docker container

Tags: php, docker, memcached

I am trying to deploy php7 slim application into docker. This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM php:7.1.2-apache

RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer


ADD sourcecode  /var/www/html

RUN composer install
RUN sed -i 's/DocumentRoot.*$/DocumentRoot \/var\/www\/html\/src/' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

This is snippet of code where Memcached initialized

```
<?php
global $config;

$cache_settings = $config['settings']['memcached'];

$memcached = new Memcached;
$memcached->addServer($cache_settings['host'], $cache_settings['port']) or die ("CANNOT connect to memcached");
```

I also have Memcached and Mysql containers are running. All staff is launching by docker-compose file. But when I am requesting for a page of my app, I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in ...

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add :

```yaml
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pecl install memcached
RUN echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

after the `FROM php:7.1.2-apache`

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the memcached package.

You can install it as follows: apt-get install memcached

Comment: It did not help. I ran script 'apt-get install memcached' and restarted conainer. But I still get error.

Comment: @R.Bogaveev you could check if the memcached extension is installed for your php version and also in your php.ini file

Comment: I ran script 'php --ini'. It outputs the following: 

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php

Loaded Configuration File:         (none)

Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: There are no ini files in specified locations .Maybe I need to put it there?

Comment: @R.Bogaveev might be in a different directory?

Comment: I use docker image php:7.1.2-apache that should work out of the box.But apparently there is no memcached packages installed. Also there is no php.ini file. Everything fine in my host machine. I am a little bit lost where or how to install memcached packages