# Unable to install memcached in php docker container

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, memcached

I tried the below, but memcached is not installed

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
# Memcached Installation
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev && \
    pecl install memcached && \
    docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```

Comment: does it give any errors? How do you check if it is installed?

Comment: You generally only run one process in a container.  If you need a separate data store (like memcached) you'd typically run it in a separate container; there is a [Docker Hub `memcached` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/memcached) that you should be able to just use.

Comment: @ArSeN I did not get any error, but memcached is not installed..@DavidMaze - let me try running it as a seperate container

Comment: So if I am using kubernetes..should I run memcached as a sidecar container along with the php-apache container ?

Comment: again: how are you checking if it is installed?

Comment: yep..nothing works :)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
#Memcached Installation
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pecl install memcached
RUN echo extension=memcached.so >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

Source: [Uncaught Error: Class 'Memcached' not found in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826441/uncaught-error-class-memcached-not-found-in-docker-container)

Comment: Thats why I asked how you checked if it did not get installed, which you never answered...